# A question regarding multi-variable \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, variable

In TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 2.10-cvs, page 676/880 there is an example as below:

```
\foreach \x / \y in {1/2,a/b} {``\x\ and \y''}
```

It is supposed to yield: "1 and 2""a and b".
But for me it gives me nothing only a blank page. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Did you put the `\foreach` in a `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: The reason is that `{``\x\ and \y''}` is not a valid `tikzpicture` draw command, so it yields nothing. You will get the expected output if using it outside the `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Recent TikZ and PGF manual is for version 3.1.5b and this example is on page 1002 :-). It works outside `ikzpicture`, as 
@Amita mentioned in her/his comment. As example of MWE: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\foreach \x / \y in {1/2,a/b} {``\x\ and \y''}
\end{preview}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Amita Please turn your comment into a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that ``` {``\x\ and \y''} ``` is not a valid `tikzpicture` drawing command, so it yields nothing. You will get the expected output if using it outside the `tikzpicture` environment.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x / \y in {1/2,a/b} {``\x\ and \y''}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case that you like to have result of your loop in a `tikzpictue`, than it should be in some node. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right, node distance=0pt]
\foreach \x / \y in {1/2,a/b} 
{
\node[on chain] {``\x\ and \y''};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. Thank you! That makes sense to me.